# getting all data against specific id along with join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables `post` and `comment`.
`table 1` post having following columns

```
id  title  description
```

`table 2` comment having following columns

```
id comment_id
```

`id` each post can have several comments.
I want to fetch single post and all its 
related comment for every `$id`.

I tried this one

```
$sql = "select * from post join comment on post.id= comment.id where post.id=$id";
```

hence $id=argument
result post 1 having comment 1,post 1 having comment 2 so i want that post 1 should not be repeated.

Comment: Can you edit your post to clarify things a little better? Its somewhat confusing as it is.

Comment: could you please tell me 'comment' table fields? Because there is no link(foreign key) in this comment fields

Comment: @MathsRkBala id in both tables are foreign key and another field which i mistype is comment for comment tabel

Comment: @shabirullah Join query join two table, so we will get two table data. If we want single table data, then we don't go for join.

Comment: @MathsRkBala but in this case i want data from two table that is all comment against specific post and also the post itself. in this i am getting the desired result but if a post have two comments than each one is print single time with repeat of post

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from the posts table and the comments table, you have to either do two queries or just ignore the duplicate posts when looping through the results. There is no way to keep the posts data from being duplicated for each comment.